# How to map remote data in according to the predefined row values in a kendo table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, kendo-grid

[image]

The above data is coming remotely...
now I have a table(kendo) shown below, how I'll be able to populate data according to the below table.

web1 should populate in front of text & app1  should populate in front of numbers & same for ip & port no.

Comment: Please write code what have tried so far?

Comment: I'm a beginner, I dont know how & where to start, normal binding I know where the remote data populates according to the field name only but here the scenario is different, so will you plz help me out...???